# PHP and VBS - Type of variables using COM

Tags: php, variables, vbscript, com

My problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202766/php-using-com-error-message-parameter-5-type-mismatch):

I'm using PHP to call an object on server with class COM, at IIS 7.

The object is well created, but when I'm using a method of it, PHP return this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Parameter 2: Type mismatch.
```

**The error occurs ALWAYS in the last parameter, regardless of whether the error is actually in the first parameter (I think so, because using another function in that same component I sent all variables fine and all are strings).**

My PHP code:

```
$com = new COM("LogicControlOEM.OEM_EjecutaOEM", NULL, CP_UTF8, 'LogicControlOEM') or die("Error al cargar el componente");

$empresa = 1;
$usuario = 'XXX';
$pass = 'XXX';

$com->InicializaOEM($empresa, 
    $usuario, 
    $pass);

var_dump($com);

$com = null;
```

I remove the optional values from the function. You can see the code below.

I tried those same parameters in a file .vbs and works fine.

---

I'm opening a new question because it's different, I don't know what type is VT_PTR in Visual Basic Script, and I want to transform a php variable to this type.

I don't know even if it is possible.

I use a php function `com_print_typeinfo()` to see the code inside the component:

```
com_print_typeinfo($com);
```

It shows the code in VBS (?):

```
class _OEM_EjecutaOEM { /* GUID={XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXXXX} */
/* DISPID=1610612736 */
function QueryInterface(
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in] --> ? [29]  */ &$riid,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [out] --> VT_PTR [26]  */ &$ppvObj 
    )
{
}
/* DISPID=1610612737 */
/* VT_UI4 [19] */
function AddRef(
    )
{
}
/* DISPID=1610612738 */
/* VT_UI4 [19] */
function Release(
    )
{
}
/* DISPID=1610678272 */
function GetTypeInfoCount(
    /* VT_PTR [26] [out] --> VT_UINT [23]  */ &$pctinfo 
    )
{
}
/* DISPID=1610678273 */
function GetTypeInfo(
    /* VT_UINT [23] [in] */ $itinfo,
    /* VT_UI4 [19] [in] */ $lcid,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [out] --> VT_PTR [26]  */ &$pptinfo 
    )
{
}
/* DISPID=1610678274 */
function GetIDsOfNames(
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in] --> ? [29]  */ &$riid,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in] --> VT_PTR [26]  */ &$rgszNames,
    /* VT_UINT [23] [in] */ $cNames,
    /* VT_UI4 [19] [in] */ $lcid,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [out] --> VT_I4 [3]  */ &$rgdispid 
    )
{
}
/* DISPID=1610678275 */
function Invoke(
    /* VT_I4 [3] [in] */ $dispidMember,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in] --> ? [29]  */ &$riid,
    /* VT_UI4 [19] [in] */ $lcid,
    /* VT_UI2 [18] [in] */ $wFlags,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in] --> ? [29]  */ &$pdispparams,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [out] --> VT_VARIANT [12]  */ &$pvarResult,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [out] --> ? [29]  */ &$pexcepinfo,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [out] --> VT_UINT [23]  */ &$puArgErr 
    )
{
}
/* DISPID=1610809345 */
function CambiaEmpresa(
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_I2 [2]  */ &$intEmpresa 
    )
{
}
/* DISPID=1610809346 */
function InicializaOEM(
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_I2 [2]  */ &$intEmpresa,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_BSTR [8]  */ &$sUserName,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_BSTR [8]  */ &$sPassword,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_BSTR [8]  */ &$sProvider,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_BSTR [8]  */ &$sDataSource,
    /* VT_PTR [26] [in][out] --> VT_BSTR [8]  */ &$sCatalog 
    )
{
}
```

Can someone explain me how the InicializaOEM function works, please? 
And why shows the comments before the variables??

Any idea is very wellcome.

Comment: Please state your full question statement here, (keep the link for reference only). But the question should stand on itself without having to look at the link. Thanks.

Comment: @OvidiuDolha it's done.